# iOS - Prevent users dragging sortable UITableViewCell to the top row

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` within which I am allowing the user to re-order cells.  All cells can be re-ordered except the top row, which must always remain as the top row.

I have used the `canMoveRowAtIndexPath` method to prevent the top row from being moveable.  However, I can't see a way to prevent the user from dragging any of the other rows and dropping them above the top row, thus breaking my top-row requirement.

How do I stop users being able to drag other rows above the top row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a UITableViewDelegate method that allows you to amend the destination index path if it doesn't meet your requirements. I think this should work:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0) {
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    else {
        return proposedDestinationPath;
    }
}
```